# Key error in work with serializer

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

**models.py:**

```
class Car(models.Model):
    # many fields

class CarOptions(models.Model):
    car = models.OneToOneField(Car, primary_key=True, related_name='options')
    color = models.CharField()
    # many other fields
```

So, I want get all information from Car and its CarOptions.

**serializer.py:**

```
class CarOptionsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    color = serializers.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = CarOptions
        fields = ('color')

class CarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    color = CarOptionsSerializer(many=True, read_only=True, )

    class Meta:
        model = Car
        fields = ('many fields', 'color', )
```

In **views.py** I have created class based on **XMLRenderer**, in **_to_xml()**  method ([link](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/renderers.py#L149)) I use:

```
self._to_xml(xml, item["color"])
```

But it does not work. I have an error:

```
KeyError: 'color'
```

I print **item**-dict and there is no key **color** in it.

How to fix that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should reference the options in the CarSerializer using the *options* field name rather than the *color* field name (as you set the related field to be *options* in the OneToOneField). You do not define a *color* field directly on the Car.

The following code works for me with the latest django and rest framework:

*models.py*

```
class CarModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)

class CarOptionsModel(models.Model):
    car = models.OneToOneField(CarModel, related_name='options')
    color = models.CharField(max_length=250)
```

*serializers.py*

```
class CarOptionsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    color = serializers.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = CarOptionsModel
        fields = ('color',)

class CarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    options = CarOptionsSerializer(read_only=True, )

    class Meta:
        model = CarModel
        fields = ('options', 'name')
```

*views.py*

```
class CarViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = CarSerializer
    queryset = CarModel.objects.all()
```

*urls.py*

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'api', CarViewSet)
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

I would note that since you define a one to one mapping, you cannot have `many=True`.

Comment: Can you show some code? I use XML Renderer, because I need some another structure (root -> main, etc)